How to elegantly display long links in flutter_inappwebview v6.0.0
I need to display user generated HTML content in a flutter app. I'm using the inappwebview plugin for this, which is full featured and generally works well.
However, it does not display long links well, e.g. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/..long_doc_id../....
On Android the font size of the whole document is reduced to almost illegible to accommodate the long links. The link does wrap onto the next line fortunately.
On iOS, the whole page is shifted to the right, cutting off the first few characters on each line. The links do not wrap. You can not scroll left or right to see the obscured parts of the page.
In summary:
Test: Loaded an HTML document containing long links.
Expected: Page to display well. Links to wrap onto the next line.
Actual: iOS page shifts to the right (as if scrolled horizontally). Android reduces font-size.
Flipping the phone to horizontal enables the doc to display correctly as it now has sufficient space to display the link. I need it to work vertically as well. As a test, I can get the document to display correctly vertically if I manually delete the links, so can confirm the long links are causing this behaviour.
I haven't found an option in InAppWebViewSettings that controls this.
What is the best way to handle this?

After a lot of testing, I've managed to solve the issue, which I'll add to this post in case it helps anyone.
The requirement in the app is to have the webview sized to fit the html content (i.e. no scrollbar and no space below). Seeing as the height is only calculated when the page is rendered, there's no elegant way to do this, so (per suggestions like Flutter and InAppWebView How to get height?), I have a JS script injected into the page to make a call out to a handler to resize:
window.flutter_inappwebview.callHandler('newHeight', newHeight);
The resizing, along with the long links, had a side-effect of scrolling the page over to the right. Adding the following JS repositioned the page correctly:
window.scrollTo(0,0)
